# Oscillating sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Does the sequence $$(-1)^n \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
Oscillates?

I have answered this below. Can anyone check if it's right?

Answer (score 5):

When $n \rightarrow \infty$ , $$(-1)^n \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right) \rightarrow \begin{cases}
\infty,\; \text{for n even}\\
-\infty,\; \text{for n odd}
 \end{cases}$$

This sequence does not converge and does not diverge to infinity.  Thus it oscillates.

Comment: Yes this is fine! $$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right) \to \infty$$ and the oscillation is given by the $(-1)^n$ term.